# Probability of a chain of 3 in an m sized Hash Table?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, probability

Consider a hash table with m slots that uses chaining for collision
resolution. The table is initially empty. What is the probability that, after three
keys are inserted, there is a chain of size 3? Assume simple uniform hashing. Would it be m/m^3?

My guess was that it would be m/m (any of the available slots) multiplied by 1/m (the same spot as the previous slot) and 1/m again, thus creating a chain size of 3.

m/m * 1/m * 1/m = m/m^3

But I just wasn't sure if this logic was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is (1/m)^2. The first one goes anywhere with probability 1. Then, there's 1/m chance the 2nd one lands in the same place, ditto for the third. So your logic is correct.